# Cant pull docker repo

Tags: docker

I created a docker repo which I wanted to pull for a local copy.
I want to create an image that can be used by anyone and everyone in the team will have a common work env.

I ran this command on my Ubuntu 14.04 :

`docker pull xanthelabs/dev`

The output is :

`Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/xanthelabs/dev
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/xanthelabs/dev`

I am new to docker and dont know what to do to remove this error. What should I be doing?

PS: I've been able to successfully pull images that are already available on the hub like ubuntu:14.04 and centos, so I know the installation is up and working.

Answer (score 1):

To pull images first you need to push something to your repo. I checked https://hub.docker.com/r/xanthelabs/dev/ and it seems that you haven't pushed anything yet.

So first (in directory with your `Dockerfile`):

```
docker build --tag xanthelabs/dev .
docker push xanthelabs/dev
```

And then:

```
docker pull xanthelabs/dev
```

For doing pushes you need to be logged in (`docker login`).

Comment: I want to make this image such that it has ubuntu:14.04 as the env. Should I start with these commands or something more specific?

Comment: You mean that it should extend `ubuntu:14.04` image? All things related to build your image should be in your `Dockerfile`. Releasing image is the same, no matter what your image is. Only thing changes is the name of the image.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. I cant make it work using these instructions. Is there some documentation for making and handling repos of docker? I am too new to this:/

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/ here you have docs about pushing images. What errors do you have?

Comment: I've successfully pushed into the repo but on pull command it still says : `Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/xanthelabs/dev`

Comment: Because you pushed tag `14.04`. Try: `docker pull xanthelabs/dev:14.04`
Tag `latest` is used if you don't specify any while pushing or pulling. But it does not mean the latest pushed tag but tag expilictly named `latest`.